# Change string in "-" and capital letter to no capital letter and space in R

Tags: r, regex, string, dplyr, tidyverse

I am having some issues with a regular expression I hope you can help me with.
I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
name <- c("Chester-le-Street",  
      "Westbury-on-Trym",
      "Easton-in-Gordano",  
      "Weston-super-Mare",
      "Bourne End-cum-Hedsor",
      "Amersham-on-the-Hill East",
      "South Westbury-on-Trym")
```

What I want to do is mainly two things:

1. remove the symbols "-"
2. Replace the first letter after where a "-" was by a capital letter.

In a way that would result in the following:

```
target_name <- c("Chester Le Street",   
          "Westbury On Trym",
          "Easton In Gordano",  
          "Weston Super Mare",
          "Bourne End Cum Hedsor",
          "Amersham On The Hill East",
          "South Westbury On Trym")
```

Been trying many different things that take very long and I never quite get exactly what I am going for nonetheless.
Would really appreciate any help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `-(\w)` as your pattern which is a dash followed by a letter. Capture the letter as group 1, then replace that with a space and the Capital letter of the captured group 1. ie  `\U\1`. Note that to do this, we escape the `\` hence have 2 backslash in the R code

```
gsub("-(\\w)", " \\U\\1", name, perl = TRUE)
[1] "Chester Le Street"         "Westbury On Trym"          "Easton In Gordano"        
[4] "Weston Super Mare"         "Bourne End Cum Hedsor"     "Amersham On The Hill East"
[7] "South Westbury On Trym"
```

Or:

```
library(stringr)
str_to_title(str_replace_all(name, '-', ' '))
[1] "Chester Le Street"         "Westbury On Trym"          "Easton In Gordano"        
[4] "Weston Super Mare"         "Bourne End Cum Hedsor"     "Amersham On The Hill East"
[7] "South Westbury On Trym"
```

Comment: was about to post `gsub('-(.)', ' \\U\\1', name, perl = T)` Upvoted yours +1

Comment: @AnilGoyal I did post that at the beginning then opted for `\w`

Comment: Yes, I think `\\w` is a good choice in favour of `.`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)

name <- c("Chester-le-Street",  
          "Westbury-on-Trym",
          "Easton-in-Gordano",  
          "Weston-super-Mare",
          "Bourne End-cum-Hedsor",
          "Amersham-on-the-Hill East",
          "South Westbury-on-Trym")

name %>%
  str_replace_all("-", " ") %>%
  str_to_title()
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO.  Seems your first answer to any post here.  `str_to_title` may capitalise unwanted characters too, though it may produce same results in the given example.  :)